# Array value duplicated

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a webshop cart, in my cart there is an array of products.

```
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo"];

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div >' + cars[i] + '</div>';
}
```

I'm getting the following:

> Saab
>   Volvo
>   BMW
>   Volvo

What I need is:

> Saab
>   Volvo x2
>   BMW

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Change your input `cars` array to match the output order/names you want?

Comment: Make this your Array:let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo x2", "BMW", "Volvo"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for counting and iterate this map for getting the rendering.

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo"],
    count = cars.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map);
    
count.forEach((v, k) => document.body.innerHTML += '<div>' + k + (v > 1 ? ' x' + v : '') + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly basic programming question. I won't hand you the answer, but I can give you the general structure of how your solution could look like.

Your input is an array with several unordered items, and the first thing you want is 
to create a new structure that groups items with the same name.

To do this, I would create a separate object that contains items and how often they appear. You should use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Loop through the cars array and add an entry to the Map for every car. You can use the car type as a key and the value should be how often you've seen the car.

So for every loop you:

- check if the car exists in the Map
- If yes, increment by 1
- If no, create a new entry and set its value to 1.

At the end you have a key->value map with items and their counts.

Now you can loop through your Map and simply output car types one by one and append `2x` if there were more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the initial array into a map. The key of each element in the map is the name of the car and the value is the number of occurrences of the car in the initial list.

Iterate the car map and generate your HTML string.

It is kind of strange that you are setting the HTML for the whole document, but the below snippet should get you what you are looking for.

```js
// initial car array
let carArr = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo"];
console.log(carArr);

// convert to a map with counts
let carObj = {};
for (let car of carArr) {
  carObj[car] = 1 + (carObj[car] || 0);
}
console.log(carObj);

// concatenate the HTML string
var s = "";
for (let car in carObj) {
  s += '<div >' + car + (carObj[car] > 1 ? ' x' + carObj[car] : '') + '</div>';
}
// set the body HTML
document.body.innerHTML += s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pre-process the list, like this:

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo"];

const map = new Map();
for (const car of cars) {
  const count = map.get(car) || 0;
  map.set(car, count + 1);
}

for (const [name, count] of map) {
   const suffix = count > 1 ? ' x' + count : '';
   document.body.innerHTML += '<div >' + name + suffix + '</div>';
}
```